# How do I trigger a view to display from within a singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a singleton class that represents a user.  Throughout the app I plan to reference the singleton when I need to access information about the user, such as user id, language preference, etc.  When I send a message to the singleton to access a particular property for which the user has not yet supplied a value I'd like to display a view that allows the user to provide a value.

Here's an example, let's say the user has not yet set her language preference.  I show an alert to notify the user and then when she clicks "OK" I redirect her to a view to set her language preference.  My problem is in that last part.  Because it's a singleton and not part of UINavigation Controller I cannot trigger the new view to show.  Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

```
-(NSString *) getUserNativeLanguageWithPromptIfNecessarry {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    nativeLanguage = [defaults stringForKey:@"nativeLanguage"];
    [self promptToSetLanguagePreferences];
    if(nativeLanguage == NULL) {
        //ask user to set language preferences
        [self promptToSetLanguagePreferences];
    }
    else {
        return nativeLanguage;
    }

}

-(void)promptToSetLanguagePreferences {
    // Create a new alert object and set initial values.
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please set your language preference settings.  Click OK to go there now."];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Language Preferences Not Set"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    // Display the alert to the user
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex==0){
        NSLog(@"userclickedCancel");

    }
    if(buttonIndex==1){
        NSLog(@"userclickedOK");
        ProfileViewController *pvc = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
        //RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PUSH PVC ONTO THE VIEW STACK.
    }
}
```

Comment: This maybe a stupid response, but can't you pass a pointer to the NavigationController to the class that needs it? (e.g., the singleton). Then you could just push the viewcontroller there, e.g., `pointerToMainNavController.pushViewController(pvc)`, etc. ?

Comment: That's a clever idea.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way for implement your pattern is to use à NSNotification. Your singleton can post multiple notification to the AppDelegate.  In your AppDelegate we can push or presentModal the viewController to select the user preference.

You can use also a delegate protocol between singleton class and your AppDelegate. it's even better because the delegate methode is synchronous with a modal viewController to retrieve the selected user preference value